# SQL Beginner - How to get items from Table1 that are associated with at least 10 items in Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably very easy, but I'm confused after looking at things online. Each item in my `Contract` table has multiple `Envelopes`. I want to find Contracts that have at least 10 envelopes. How do I go about this?

I've tried the following

```
select c.*, COUNT(e.ID)  
from [Contract] c
INNER JOIN Envelope e ON e.ContractID = c.ID
Group By c.ID
HAVING Count(e.ID) > 10
```

And I get

`Column 'Contract.PresenterUserID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

I haven't dealt with aggregate or group by clauses before, so I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: You have tried something, what was the result? Btw, `at least 10` is not the same as `> 10`.

Comment: yes, what was the output of this query? With that we can help from there.

Comment: Your query looks reasonable, although you should use `>= 10` for "have at least 10 envelopes".  How is it not working?

Comment: What was the problem with the query given? It looks good to me. At least means >= though.

Comment: Query doesn`t look bad. Add some data samples.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Sorry, I have now added the query output to my question. It doesn't like one of the columns of my first table.

Comment: This doesn't sound like MySQL. Have you confused the DBMS?

Comment: The use of square braces suggests SQL Server, so I tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: That makes a difference. In MySQL you can use above query; in most other DBMS you can't. Make sure that every column of c you show is either in the GROUP BY clause, e.g. `GROUP BY id, contract_no` or aggregated, e.g. `select c.id, max(c.contract_no)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MySQL will accept your query.  So, I am assuming that you are not using MySQL or the system has full group by turned on.

Here is another approach that will work in any database:

```
select c.*, e.cnt
from [Contract] c inner join
     (select e.ContractId, count(*) as cnt
      from Envelope e
      group by e.ContractId
      having count(*) >= 10
     ) e
     on e.ContractID = c.ID;
```

This moves the aggregation to a subquery, before the join.  You can then take all the columns from the `contract` table.

Comment: Thanks! Best answer because it lets me keep all of the columns in the `contract` table and it taught me something. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close. You must include all fileds in the selectt either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Try this:

```
select c.id, c.PresenterUserID, COUNT(e.ID)  
from [Contract] c
INNER JOIN Envelope e ON e.ContractID = c.ID
Group By c.ID, c.PresenterUserID
HAVING Count(e.ID) >= 10
```